# foreach vs sum for multiple fields

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have a class defined as

```
class P
{
        public List<P> children; 
        public int Val1;
        public int Val2;
}
```

As you can see the class has a list of objects of the same class. I instantiate the class and fill the list:

```
P myp = new P { children = new List<P> {new P {Val1 = 1, Val2 = 1}, new P {Val1 = 2, Val2 = 2}}};
```

Now, if I want to sum up the values of the children's fields and place them in the appropriate parent field I can do

```
foreach (var p in myp.children)
{
        myp.Val1 += p.Val1;
        myp.Val2 += p.Val2;
}
```

which seems efficient but uglier or I can do

```
myp.Val1 = myp.children.Sum(p => p.Val1);
myp.Val2 = myp.children.Sum(p => p.Val2);
```

which is more readable but iterates through the list twice.

Is there a beautiful AND efficient way of doing this? Or am I stuck with the foreach?

Comment: Did you measure the time for both methods with expected list sizes? Maybe it doesn't matter much in final execution time so you can go for "readable".

Comment: I dont think the first one is ugly

Comment: Performance-wise the difference for the list size is tiny. Just wanted to see some possible solutions. Selecting the one that fits my code as the answer, but upvoting everything because I think all are good. :)

Comment: One consideration: If your performance does decrease due to excessive iterations, you could consider parallelizing the operation much easier using the .Sum LINQ method. Using your iterative version will fail when done in parallel because of the shared state unless you handle that explicitly (Interlock or MapReduce).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes we developers get neurotic about the silliest things. I've been there way too much. I don't think there is any reason to change it.

Still, if you want to, here is an idea:

```
class P
{
    public List<P> children;
    public int Val1;
    public int Val2;

    public void Add( P p )
    {
        this.Val1 += p.Val1;
        this.Val2 += p.Val2;
    }
}
```

And then you can do...

```
myp.children.ForEach( myp.Add );
```

Answer (score 3):

If performances are relevant in your case and you are going to reuse the sum of two values you could write an extension method:

```
public static void SumMultiple<T>(this IEnumerable<T> x, Func<T, int> selector1, Func<T, int> selector2, out int a, out int b)
{
    a = b = 0;
    foreach (var item in x)
    {
        a += selector1(item);
        b += selector2(item);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
int val1, val2;
collection.SumMultiple(a => a.A, b => b.B, out val1, out val2);

Console.WriteLine("Val1 is {0}, Val2 is {1}", val1, val2);
```

Otherwise a foreach loop is welcome in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Unless it is prooved to be two slow I like

```
myp.Val1 = myp.children.Sum(p => p.Val1); 
myp.Val2 = myp.children.Sum(p => p.Val2);
```

As it makes it easier to move code about and the **reflector code**.

Combining many operations into the same loop may be faster, (but normally you don’t care about speed that much), however it make it a lot harder to extract code into a separate method that is the bases for most refactoring’s.

**Remember that these days it takes a lot longer (often by a factor 100 or more) to read data from main memory into the processor cache, then it takes the processor to read over data that is already in its cache.**   On  the 2nd iteration over the same data often takes much less time than the first.

Be very carefully if you use a profiler, as most profilers don’t pick up the effect of the processor cache,  profilers tent to also fill the processor cache with their timing code.

Comment: Surely cache would be an argument for one loop. If children was a very large collection it could push the start of the collection out of the cache again. One loop means that access to other members on the same object will be extremely fast as the registers are already set up.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, The collection would have to be **very** large to fill up most level 2 (or 3) caches these days.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the same `foreach` (looks pretty good for me though) but written with List.ForEach method will do:

```
myp.children.ForEach(p => { myp.Val1 += p.Val1; myp.Val2 += p.Val2; });
```

Comment: This `ForEach` is not Linq method, but a List object method.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I thought it is defined in System.Linq. Thanks, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To me the first method seems cleaner, more readable, and more efficient (twice through list & creating 2 lamda's on second)

Answer (score 1):

I guess For each is fine. One iteration and simple to read and understand. But below is a **weird** code which does it using Sum.

```
myp.Val1 = myp.children.Sum(p => { myp.Val2 += p.Val2; return p.Val1; });
```